# MacOS menu bar changes color from black to white when switching virtual desktops – possible to make pin it to a single color?

Tags: macos, macos-bigsur

So my menu bar changes its color when I switch virtual desktops. On desktop 1, I have black text on a white menu bar. On Desktop 2, it is white text on white menu bar. On desktop 3 and beyond, it is white text on a dark menu bar:

[image]

Not sure whether this is a bug, but the menu bar on Desktop 2 is mostly unreadable. I also tried switching "Allow wallpaper tinting in windows" off, however, this didn't fix the problem. I would prefer to have the same menu bar (like on Desktop 1) on each virtual desktop. Is that possible?

Comment: That seems strange... what is your version of macOS? Also, have you tried changing the background and see if it persists?

Comment: Weird. I guess this is a bug. After changing the wallpaper to something else and back again, the colors of the menubar persist. FTR, I'm on Big Sur.

Comment: …and it happened again. So every time it happens, I have to change the wallpaper. Then it's gone. After some time, it happens again. I will to keep an eye on when this exactly happens and when not.

Comment: Well, I meant checking another background altogether. Maybe it has something to do with this specific image.

Comment: I've heard this mentioned as a Big Sur bug. You'll have to wait for Apple to fix it, I think, or maybe use Reduce Transparency in Accessibility prefs in the meantime.

Comment: @Tetsujin do you remember where this was mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, no, it's a bit vague to track down. I shall hand back my google-fu black belt ;)) Probably on https://apple.stackexchange.com but I haven't been able to find it. It may have just been in comments.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414369/big-sur-menu-bar-changes-color-from-black-to-white-when-switching-virtual-deskto

Comment: @Tetsujin I didn't know about the migration feature, will remember that for the future!